# Не получается получить количество перекрестков в городе из nominatim.openstreetmap на языке Python

Tags: json, requests, openstreetmap

Я пытаюсь получить количество перекрестков в городе нетания от nominatim.openstreetmap, но в результате получаю 0 перекрестков, хотя на самом деле это не так.

Также не могу получить количество улиц.

При этом, если я например попрошу найти больницы, то получаю правильный ответ.

```
import requests

# координаты города Нетания
lat = 32.3329
lon = 34.8599

# координаты полигона границ города Нетания
north = 32.3396
south = 32.2787
west = 34.8185
east = 34.9158

# формирование запроса к API OpenStreetMap для поиска перекрестков в заданной области
url = f"https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=crossing&format=json&bounded=1&viewbox={west},{south},{east},{north}"

# отправка запроса
response = requests.get(url)

# обработка ответа
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    count = len(data)
    print(f"Найдено {count} перекрестков в городе Нетания")
else:
    print("Произошла ошибка при выполнении запроса")
```

Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете ввести этот же запрос вручную в адресную строку и также не получите ответа, следовательно что-то с вашим запросом не так.
Вам необходимо тщательнее формировать запрос, так как перекрестки не задать просто словом "crossing"
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_features возможно эта ссылка поможет